# Should I move an HVAC vent to the ceiling or on the opposite interior wall?

Tags: hvac, ducts, air

The below picture shows the current position of the vent (the white area over the sink). The blue patch above the toilet is a small window.

The plan is to relocate the bath tub and position it along the wall so it will cover the vent. The new layout is in the second picture. The glass between toilet and tub is optional.

I am trying to understand where I should vent this duct. Should I do it on the ceiling or completely move it on the opposite wall? I don't know if I can try to re route it in the vertical wall, that will add some direction changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd just shorten the duct and put it in the ceiling. It's a matter of space and your prerogative. Ideally it's near the outside wall to maintain comfort in cold/hot weather.

Comment: I am afraid that if I put it on the ceiling hot water vapors and humidity will get in and the duct will rust
as far as I understand it needs to vent out near the window to avoid cold patches and condense on that window. The air needs to move near that window ...not sure how it helped in that sense in the current position

Comment: If your duct rusts it's because you don't have (or don't use) an exhaust fan. That's an unrelated issue that will result in other problems anyway.

Comment: I would position it just outside the shower bay, where it'll circulate air through both the shower and toilet areas.

Comment: I do have a fan there as well at the center of the room on the ceiling

Comment: Good. Put a timer switch on it and run the fan after every shower for 30-120 minutes, depending on climate and effectiveness. You should have virtually no condensation on the walls and ceiling.

Comment: positioning it just outside the shower bay means I will have to do some routing in the framing and.. I am already having an issue there (trying to conceal the vent and the drain ) ...hmm if I think twice the problem is not that big because before there was a 24" deep wall separating the toilet sit and the sink there (and hiding the pipes I am trying to relocate)

Comment: the timer is a good idea, If I put the vent on the top just out of the shower/bath tub glass enclosure that might work.

Comment: Even better than a timer: a humidity sensing switch. Ours is built right into the fan itself - turns itself on when it's humid, turns itself off when it's "dry". I think it's 60% from the factory and _not_ adjustable, but it works pretty well and nobody forgets to turn it on or off.